# cache-control in google dev tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache

I'm playing around with Chrome Dev Tools and I have a question regarding the use of cache-control.

I have a simple app with an app.js and an application.css, and when I check disable cache in the toolbar both resources are downloaded from the server, but when I uncheck it, app.js is not downloaded again as it's in the browser cache, but the application.css is downloaded again.

I checked the response headers expecting to see a cache-control: no-cache for the application.css but... it's not there. Actually, the information in the response header regarding cache-control for application.css and for app.js is the same: there's no information.

Anyone knows or have any idea why this could be?

Thanks

EDIT: request and response headers

```
"request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": XXXXXXXXXX,
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Accept-Encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br"
            },
            {
              "name": "Host",
              "value": XXXXXXXXXX
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Language",
              "value": "es-ES,es;q=0.8"
            },
            {
              "name": "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept",
              "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": XXXXXXXXXX
            },
            {
              "name": "Cookie",
              "value": XXXXXXXXXX
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            },
            {
              "name": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "max-age=0"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [],
          "cookies": [
            {
              XXXXXXXXXX
            }
          ],
          "headersSize": 527,
          "bodySize": 0
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "statusText": "OK",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Date",
              "value": "Fri, 21 Apr 2017 08:41:14 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "Last-Modified",
              "value": "Sun, 16 Apr 2017 11:17:04 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "Server",
              "value": "nginx/1.10.1"
            },
            {
              "name": "ETag",
              "value": "\"58f352b0-7ad\""
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "text/html"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Ranges",
              "value": "bytes"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Length",
              "value": "1965"
            }
          ],
```

Comment: Can you show us application.css request and response HTTP headers? You can use Chrome DevTools [Copy All as HAR](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#copy) feature.

Comment: Sure thing, I just edited my question.

Comment: `Cache-Control: max-age=0` instructs browser not to use cached response without revalidation on server. How do you navigate to your application page?

Comment: I edited my comment. Where does `1492341424555` came from? Is it file revision or cache buster (current time or random number)?

Comment: That number is autogenerated when building the css file with so that it will be regenerated when the css changes. But for the same number and multiple reloads of the page that should be cached.
I don´t understand your question, how do I navigate to my application page?

Comment: Did you paste URL into address bar and hit Return or press F5 or Ctrl+F5 or press a link on another page?

Comment: Please make sure that you showed all headers of correct request and response, that Disable cache is unchecked and that all Chrome extensions are disabled (better try in Incognito mode).

Comment: I copy pasted the url on the address bar. The Disable cache is unchecked and I'm testing in incognito mode. Then I press reload icon every time I want to reload the page. Everything is cached but the css file.